# Error code: `unable to get the pivottables property of the worksheet class` when same code works for different pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am writing a macro which creates several pivot tables. All but 1 table runs fine, but I am getting a runtime error code for the one below: `unable to get the pivottables property of the worksheet class`

```
Dim PT As Excel.PivotTable
    Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "GFCID!R1C1:R117200C129", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable( _
            TableDestination:="'source'!R1C1", TableName:="Banking Book Pivot", _
            DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    With PT.PivotFields( _
        "IRU")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    
'    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Banking Book Pivot").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
'        "Banking Book Pivot").PivotFields("GFCID"), "Count of GFCID", xlCount
    
'    PT.AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
'        "Banking Book Pivot").PivotFields("GFCID"), "Count of GFCID", xlCount

'    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Banking Book Pivot").PivotTables("Banking Book Pivot").PivotFields("GFCID" & Chr(10) & "Count")
'        .Orientation = xlDataField
'        .Function = xlCount
'        .Name = "Count of GFCID"
'    End With
```

I have tried each of the three codes which are commented out, and they all get the same error. The first two codes work with other pivot tables in the macro. The data set for this pivot table is much larger than the others, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: Most likely the `ActiveSheet` is not the right one. But you should just use `PT`.

Comment: @BigBen That was indeed the problem. Setting the pivot table sheet to active fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: No don't do that. Use the worksheet in question: `Worksheets("Source")`. Or just use `PT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ActiveSheet`. Use `PT`:

```
With PT
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("GFCID"), "Count of GFCID", xlCount
End With
```